# Why do Airbnb hosts often refuse to provide Anmeldung?

Tags: germany

I am looking up Apartments in Germany, and I often find that they refuse to offer Wohnungsgeberbestätigung (required for anmeldung). Why is this? What is gained from not offering?

Comment: By *providing Anmeldung*, do you mean a *Wohnungsgeberbestätigung*?

Comment: I hired an Airbnb for two months when I first moved to Germany and I did get a *Wohnungsgeberbestätigung* for my *Anmeldung*. I don't know why many are reluctant. Speculation, but maybe they don't want the authorities to know they're renting out on Airbnb, or they (wrongly) worry it turns them into a regular landlord, or they don't want to deal with people receiving mail at the address? They'd need to provide a separate mailbox, at least.

Answer (score 3):

If the Airbnb is considered a **Beherbergungsbetrieb** (*commercial accommodation*) and the renting period is less than 3 months then a simplified registration is only required.

- [§§29, 30 Bundesmeldegesetz (BMG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0274)

Under such circumstances (less than 3 months), a *Wohnungsgeberbestätigung* need not be issued.

Answer (score 1):

There is an ongoing struggle how platforms like Airbnb or Uber fit into the legal system. Before the rise of the internet platforms, subletting a room or using a ride-share was a little, informal part of the economy. Now it is big business and government regulators are trying to catch up. This might make the host reluctant to sign anything that will come to the attention of the authorities.

- The Airbnb host may be a tenant without the permission of the landlord to sublease part or all of their apartment.
- The Airbnb host may be pretending to still live at the address, even if it is almost continuously rented out.
- The landlord may be trying to obscure that a formerly residential property has been converted into a short-term rental.

Airbnb is fighting hard to avoid reporting to the local tax authorities. Not every host does properly self-report.